# Synaptic Dependency Error

Tags: 11.04, synaptic

Every time i install/remove something via Synaptic, I always get this error

```
E: foomatic-filters: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
E: rsyslog: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
E: foo2zjs: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: samba-common: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
E: samba-common-bin: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: smbclient: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

The following is what I get from executing the following command:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

http://pastebin.com/h1cCJDKF

If you happen to know what this error really mean and how I can fix it (if it is necessary + easy to do so) please let me know!

Thanks in advance!

FYI:

My problem was actually to get MusicBrainz Picard installed on my Ubuntu Natty but after several reinstallations, the programme still fails to start up. I am wondering whether the error I get from Synaptic is an explanation to this.

The following is the error I get from installing Picard from the Software Centre

http://pastebin.com/EDDRM3c1

Thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

Is this it ? 
http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard#Download

Use archive manager and read the install.txt

http://ftp.musicbrainz.org/pub/musicbrainz/picard/picard-0.16.tar.gz

Maybe your missing something important Python ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But after following the instructions, I arrived at this error 

http://pastebin.com/Ld9UQ2Bj I seem to have Python 2.7 installed

Comment: And also, this still leaves my Synaptic problem unfixed.